# How to override the default Route to any desired route in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to override the default routes of APIs in swagger document. My intention is to show only data contracts in the document and not show the endpoints.

I have tried using `OperationFilter` and `DocumentFilter`, I could not figure out a way to replace the path.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean about show only data contracts instead of endpoint? You need to provide more details to make other people understand your issue.